# How does HTML abbr translate to Rmarkdown via Rstudio?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm trying to get abbreviations working on a HTML document created with Rmarkdown via Rstudio.
This syntax does not seem to be working

```
AB1 is an enzime...
    
*[AB1]: Abbreviation 1
```

But, in the final HTMl document I do not get a tooltip when the cursor passes over AB1.

Any ideas? Overall, I want to avoid manually writing

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A list of abbrevations will be automatically built if the document contains HTML abbr elements. You can use the following code:

```
---
title: "test"
ouput: html_document
---

### Title

<abbr title="Abbrevation 1">AB1</abbr>
```

Output:

[image]

You can hover over and click on it. The title of list of abbrevations can be customized using `loa-title` field in the YAML header of your Rmarkdown document.